# Get the last value in a comma-separated string

Tags: php, string, csv, text-extraction

I have a string with numbers, stored in `$numbers`:

```
3,6,86,34,43,52
```

What's the easiest way to get the last value after the last comma? In this case the number `52` would be the last value, which I would like to store in a variable.

The number can vary in size, so trying:

```
substr($numbers, -X)
```

does not help me out I think.

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

Just use [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to get the position of the last comma and then use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the string after the last comma, e.g.

```
$str = "3,6,86,34,43,52";
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, ",") + 1);
```

output:

```
52
```

Answer (score 0):

Just explode the string by the separator character and pick the last of the resulting tokens:

```
<?php
$string = '3,6,86,34,43,52'; 
$tokens = explode(',', $string);
echo end($tokens);
```

An alternative would be to use a regular expression:

```
<?php
$string = '3,6,86,34,43,52'; 
preg_match('/,([0-9]+)$/', $string, $tokens);
echo end($tokens);
```

Personally I have the opinion that efficiency is less important that easy of reading and understanding the code these days. Computation power is cheap, developers are expensive. That is why I would use the first approach, expect when the number of elements in the string gets big.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$numbers = "3,6,86,34,43,52";
$arr = explode(",",$numbers);

echo $arr[count($arr)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to an array, and get the last element:

```
$numbers = '3,6,86,34,43,52';
$arr = explode(',', $numbers);
echo $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

Comment: To combine the last two lines you could use `substr_count()`, e.g. `echo $number = explode(',', $numbers)[substr_count($numbers, ",")];`

Answer (score 0):

A direct, single-function approach would be to trim every upto the last comma.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v70mJ))

```
$numbers = "3,6,86,34,43,52";
echo preg_replace('/.*,/', '', $numbers);
// 52
```